# The memset function is giving me an error when using VS C++

Tags: c, memset

I am using memset to clear a buffer:

```
char header_buffer[100];
memset(header_buffer[100],0,sizeof(header_buffer[100]));
```

I'm getting a compile error:

```
Error   C2664   
'void *memset(void *,int,size_t)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'char' to 'void *'
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Why did you include the size of the array?

Comment: `header_buffer[100]` is one (1) element in `header_buffer`, specifically the non-existent element 100. It is not the whole array. It is a single character. You probably want `memset(header_buffer,0,sizeof(header_buffer));`, but I can't be certain without more context in the question.

Comment: Unrelated: consider as an alternative `char header_buffer[100] = {};`. [Here's a good run-down on the many initialization options available in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization).

Answer (score 1):

The arguments need to be a pointer to the array, not a single element from the array:

```
char header_buffer[100];
memset(header_buffer, 0, sizeof(header_buffer));
```